# Fixed table header to top of window upon scroll, jumps/skips a row. jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, sticky, tableheader

Please see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/22KFS/3/) i've created to replicate my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/22KFS/3/

In my project, I have created a table, which is sortable. I've used the [jquery table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/) to do this which is a very simple jquery plugin. The table sorter is also included in the jsfidde. If you click the table headers, you will notice it sorts the table columns from descending to ascending.

This is fine, the problem I have is...

On my live website, the table is about 125 rows high. And I want to avoid paginating the table at all costs.

So my idea was to fix the table header upon scrolling with jQuery, which is nearly working. Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/22KFS/3/). The jQuery I've used to fix the header to the top of the pages works.

The problem is because the table header becomes fixed, the table shifts up a row, and makes it very glitchy.

Can anyone help me remove the glitchness, and stop it skipping a row when it reaches the top of window.

Would really appreciate any help thanks.

See jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/22KFS/3/

**jQuery**

```
var $window     = $(window),
    $tableHead  = $(".table-head"),
    offset      = $tableHead.offset();

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $tableHead.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $tableHead.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table-sorter" width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">         
    <thead>
            <tr class="table-head">
                <th width="100" height="18" valign="middle">Number</th>
                <th width="100" height="18" valign="middle">First Name</th>
                <th width="100" height="18" valign="middle">Surname</th>
                <th width="100" height="18" valign="middle">System</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Wordpress</td>     
            </tr>

            ... ...

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Recomend to look on http://biathlontime.com/2011-2012/ruhpolding/women-individual/ — the jquery plugin used there is just great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved your problem. In case you hadn't realised already, the reason it jumps is because you are essentially removing the header row from the table when you make it position fixed, so the rest of the table jumps up to fill the gap.

The solution? Well, it's up for debate. To prove my point, all I've done is add a new temporary header when you make the actual header fixed. This keeps the table in place and allows the header to move down. When you scroll back up, that temporary header then gets removed.

Is this the best way? Not sure, you maybe want to clone the real header as a temporary solution, just in case of graphical glitches. This would also mean that in case of headers with multiple lines (therefore pushing the height down), the effect would be maintained as it's taking an exact clone.

Anyway, on with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/22KFS/5/

```
$("#table-sorter").tablesorter({
 widgets: ['zebra']
});


var $window     = $(window),
    $tableHead  = $(".table-head"),
    offset      = $tableHead.offset();

$window.scroll(function() {


    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $tableHead.addClass('fixed');
        if ($('#table-sorter thead tr.temp').length <= 0){
            $('#table-sorter thead').append('<tr class="temp"><td>hello</td></tr>');
        }
    } else {
        $tableHead.removeClass('fixed');
        $('tr.temp').remove();
    }


});
```

​
Good luck.

**EDIT**

Here's the working product using clone()
http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/22KFS/8/

Code:

```
$("#table-sorter").tablesorter({
     widgets: ['zebra']
});


var $window     = $(window),
    $tableHead  = $(".table-head"),
    offset      = $tableHead.offset();

$window.scroll(function() {


    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $tableHead.addClass('fixed');
        if ($('#table-sorter thead tr.temp').length <= 0){
            $tableHead.clone().appendTo('#table-sorter thead').removeClass('fixed').addClass('temp');
        }
    } else {
        $tableHead.removeClass('fixed');
        $('tr.temp').remove();
    }


});    ​
```

Comment: Thats is clever. Its not masively smoother because the styles like you said are a little off, and I can't seem to fix with css. It's only off by a few pixels. Is it actually possible to clone stuff? That would awesome if I could clone the header and the sorting functionality worked. That way there would be any table movement. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: You will have to forgive me, I'm on my phone so can't give you complete code. See here for jQuery clone http://api.jquery.com/clone/. I think you will want to clone and then remove and add a temporary class/id, this will allow you to remove it later: $tableHead.clone().removeClass('fixed').addClass('temp');   This should clone it in the same place and change the class to temp. Use the same code from before to remove. As I say I'm on my phone so this isn't tested, you may have to change it slightly, use the link I gave you to help.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm on iPhone too do will check this out in a few hours and get back to. I'm quite new to javascript and jquery, but it doesn't look too tricky.

Comment: Hi Josh, just tried it out with clone: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/22KFS/8/ My line was slightly wrong, should be `$tableHead.clone().appendTo('#table-sorter thead').removeClass('fixed').addClass('temp');` I've also made the header text bigger so you can see that it works with odd shaped heights and such.

Comment: awesome, just in time too. I check this out now. Thanks

Comment: worked perfect thanks. Could not get it to work in IE7 but conditionally but I've conditionally turned it off for IE7 and below.